# How can I use an NSTimer (or other) to make events happen after a certain time in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, wait

I am using Xcode to create a Cocoa app for Mac OSX written in Objective-C.

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)clickToLaunchAppButtonClicked:(id)sender; {
//I want to hide the click to load app button
[clickToLoadButton setEnabled:NO];
[clickToLoadButton setHidden:YES];

//***I want to make the app wait for 1 second (This is where I'm stuck!)***

//I want to show the loading label
[loadingLabel setEnabled:YES];
[loadingLabel setHidden:NO];

//I want to show the loading progress bar and initialize it
[loadingProgressBar setHidden:NO];
[loadingProgressBar startAnimation:self];

//***I want to make the app wait for 3 seconds (Again, I don't know how to do this!)***

//I want to stop the loading progress bar animation
[loadingProgressBar stopAnimation:self];

//I want to hide the loading progress bar and loading label
[loadingLabel setHidden:YES];
[loadingLabel setEnabled:NO];
[loadingLabel setHidden:YES];
}
```

How can I make the app wait/pause for a few seconds? I tried the `wait()`, `delay()` or `pause()` functions, but they freeze the app, which is not what I want. Should I use an `NSTimer`? If so, please give me a **simple** way to implement it.

Comment: Why are you adding fake progress bars and unnecessary delays to your application? How does this benefit the user?

Comment: You don't understand: It's a criteria for a junior high computer project. I am the most advanced kid in my class, so the teacher made me do an app where I need to make it look like it's loading :D

Comment: Well, since this is a learning exercise, I think you should get both @Maudicus' answer and mine to work. Maybe use his for one of the delays, and mine for the other. I think GCD is the "modern" way to do it, but all the different approaches have their benefits. `NSTimer` is also a perfectly valid approach by the way, though it would normally be used for a repeated delay (such as where you do something every 10 seconds). Another benefit of `NSTimer` is you can cancel something previously scheduled. Maybe you should try to get that working as well. ;)

Comment: You could use `NSTimer` to increase the progress bar several times until it's finished, perhaps a quarter of a second between each increase.

Comment: Could you tell me how I could implement an NSTimer in my app? Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the code you want to run on the 3 second delay in another method (delayedLoad) and use `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:`

```
[self performSelector:@selector(delayedLoad) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
```

EDIT - spelling it out more in response to your comment

to create the other method, include this code in the same .m file (AppDelegate.m or similar)

```
-(void)delayedLoad
{

//I want to stop the loading progress bar animation
[loadingProgressBar stopAnimation:self];

//I want to hide the loading progress bar and loading label
[loadingLabel setHidden:YES];
[loadingLabel setEnabled:NO];
[loadingLabel setHidden:YES];
}
```

And your existing method becomes

```
-(IBAction)clickToLaunchAppButtonClicked:(id)sender; {
//I want to hide the click to load app button
[clickToLoadButton setEnabled:NO];
[clickToLoadButton setHidden:YES];

//***I want to make the app wait for 1 second (This is where I'm stuck!)***

//I want to show the loading label
[loadingLabel setEnabled:YES];
[loadingLabel setHidden:NO];

//I want to show the loading progress bar and initialize it
[loadingProgressBar setHidden:NO];
[loadingProgressBar startAnimation:self];
[self performSelector:@selector(delayedLoad) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
}
```

This is how you implement the 3 second delay.  Hopefully you can extend this to implement the 1 second delay

Comment: It's too complicated, I don't know how to put it in and errors show up. Please help :) (I am a brand new programmer)

Comment: @CocoaCoder I modified my answer to give you code to implement 1 delay, please use it, and then extend it (another method performed on delay) to have the 1 second delay as well. You can learn from adding the second delay once you see the first delay working

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the new Grand Central Dispatch API instead.

For example:

```
-(IBAction)clickToLaunchAppButtonClicked:(id)sender {
  //I want to hide the click to load app button
  [clickToLoadButton setEnabled:NO];
  [clickToLoadButton setHidden:YES];

  // wait one second
  dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
  dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    //I want to show the loading label
    [loadingLabel setEnabled:YES];
    [loadingLabel setHidden:NO];

    //I want to show the loading progress bar and initialize it
    [loadingProgressBar setHidden:NO];
    [loadingProgressBar startAnimation:self];

    // execute the rest after 3 seconds
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 3.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

      //I want to stop the loading progress bar animation
      [loadingProgressBar stopAnimation:self];

      //I want to hide the loading progress bar and loading label
      [loadingLabel setHidden:YES];
      [loadingLabel setEnabled:NO];
      [loadingLabel setHidden:YES];
    });
  });
}
```

There are three advantages:

- It's less code, and cleaner. You don't need to define extra methods and all your code is in one place.
- The GCD api is increadibly fast, though in your example it probably doesn't matter much, sometimes this is important, especially on an iPhone where "fast" also means "longer battery life"
- The code to be executed shares the scope with the code that calls it. Any variables in the outer code, are available in the code to be executed later

Comment: Oops! It worked well the first time, but then it didn't work anymore... It hides everything instantly :( Is this `C++` code? If it is `C++` code, how can I implement it to make it work? BTW: I am making this app in `Objective-C` for Mac, not iPod :D

Comment: It's a hybrid between Objective-C and C/C++. You said it works once but then stopped working, what did you change and what error are you getting? Also, do you have ARC turned on? I'll need to update the example a bit if you are not using ARC.

Comment: I don't know what ARC is... I'm brand new to programming. I didn't change anything in the code, by the way. Please help :D

Comment: ARC is "automatic reference counting" you should google it and have fun learning all about it (basically, it's a memory management system Apple recently added to Mac OS X). It may or may not be turned on depending how your project is configured in Xcode. If I have time after work I'll check if my code has any bugs in it. What error did you get? Or if I don't have time, you could always post it as another question and someone is sure to help you figure it out.

Comment: It didn't show me any error; Xcode sometimes lags on my computer; that's maybe why the code didn't work... I updated Xcode from 4.1 to 4.2 today and I finally see the arc option, but I still don't know how to use it... Please help and thanks :D

Comment: ARC is enabled when you create a project, or for existing projects with `edit -> refactor -> convert to arc...`. You should at least read everything on this page before using it as ARC changes the language quite a bit: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html

Comment: There were a couple of small mistakes in my answer's code. I've fixed them now, does it work for you?